# How to rotate part of image diagonally and stick edges together?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-effects, effects

I want to figure out how could be done this kind of effect.

Imaging you have an image with road and you want to bend it diagonally to give an impression of vertical road.

I already tried rotating it 90 degrees and distort it but i don't know how to stick everything on that bend line.

Can you please suggest how to do this?

Here is original image and next to it effect i want to achieve.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Hi Ivan and welcome to GDSE. Please try to make your question more specific. Which effect are you talking about? I guess you mean the way the ground is rotated 90 degrees to give the impression of a vertical road? What have you tried and why didn't it work? Maybe show us the image you are working with?

Comment: This is not an "effect", it's time spent editing the photo. There's no magic button that will get you that.

Comment: Duplicate photo into a new layer, rotate 90 degrees, use layer mask to hide the top part of the now vertical duplicate of the photo diagonally, and feather the edge by further masking it out and possibly back in with a soft round brush because that would give you the most control to make it less uniform. The key in this photo is also that there's a ton of ground and not a lot of sky and more importantly the photo is cropped from the right side before the sky would appear. You may also need to use like liquify, smudge tool, free transform warp or liquify to make sure roads meet.

Comment: tl;dr copy of the photo + 90 degree rotation + diagonal layer mask. That's like a good chunk of the "effect". The rest is just tons of small adjustments.

Answer (score 1):

A photo is put as a layer to a much bigger canvas to get some working room. Then the photo has been split by making a selection with the polygonal lasso. A part was cut & pasted to another layer and rotated 90 degrees:

[image]

The moved part is distorted to make the seam fit:

[image]

I found it was easiest to skew the piece and continue with Edit > Transform > Distort.

Much manual edits is needed to make some well visible objects nicely bent on the seam. My image hasn't such elements except the mountains in the background. They are left with a hard edged joint. The layers must be merged before edits on the seam.

It was surprising how little was left in the vertical part if it wasn't originally much bigger than the non-processed part. Also the loss of details is remarkable, something much sharper than a screenshot (this was one from Wikipedia) is needed as a starting point if the result must be acceptable on the screen.